# Java Split array or range into N chunks

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to split an array or range of numbers from 0 to N into N/n chunks.

I am currently making an arrayList of N elements

```
    List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        arrayList.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }

    System.out.println(arrayList);


    int numOfChunks = (int)Math.ceil((double)arrayList.size() / numOfchunks);
    int[][] output = new int[numOfChunks][];

    for(int i = 0; i < numOfChunks; ++i) {
        int start1 = i * numOfChunks;
        int length = Math.min(arrayList.size() - start1, numOfChunks);

        int[] temp = new int[length];
        System.arraycopy(arrayList, start1, temp, 0, length);
        output[i] = temp;
    }
    System.out.println(output);
```

However, i keep getting an error on this line

```
    System.arraycopy(arrayList, start1, temp, 0, length);
```

I believe it is because i am using an array list. I have tried with a regular array but i get a NegativeArraySizeException error.

Comment: If you want to copy an ArrayList, use `new ArrayList( old.subList(start,start+length) );`

Comment: you are using the variable `numOfchunks` incorrectly? you are using the variable on declaration statement in line#9?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you use the variable "numOfChunks" and "numOfchunks" wrongly.
It is better to rename the variables so that it is more easy to understand.

```
int numOfChunks = (int)Math.ceil((double)arrayList.size() / numOfchunks);
int[][] output = new int[numOfChunks][];
```

to

```
int numOfSubArrays= (int)Math.ceil((double)arrayList.size() / subArraySize);
int[][] output = new int[numOfSubArrays][];
```

and

```
for(int i = 0; i < numOfChunks; ++i) {
    int start1 = i * numOfChunks;
    int length = Math.min(arrayList.size() - start1, numOfChunks);

    int[] temp = new int[length];
    System.arraycopy(arrayList, start1, temp, 0, length);
    output[i] = temp;
}
System.out.println(output);
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < numOfSubArrays; ++i) {
    int arrayListPosition = i * subArraySize;
    int length = Math.min(arrayList.size() - arrayListPosition, subArraySize);

    int[] temp = new int[length];
    System.arraycopy(arrayList, arrayListPosition, temp, 0, length);
    output[i] = temp;
}
System.out.println(output);
```